# NodeJS Azure Functions used as a Messenger Bot return an mscorlib error

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger, azure-functions

I'm trying to use Azure Functions as a Messenger bot server using a Generic Webhook. The problem I'm running into is that even running this simple code (most of it is commented out to try & figure out the issue) results in an error (below the code):

```
module.exports = function (context, data) {
    context.log('Webhook was triggered!');

            context.res = {
                status: 403,
                body: ''
            }

    context.done();
}
```

> Function completed (Failure,
>   Id=fb0f2178-8b98-4163-a5ae-7ab68eff47cd) 
>   Exception while executing function: Functions.StriverMessenger.
>   mscorlib: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Why is this error occurring and how do I get this to work? If I fake out the querystring entries in the *run* mode inside Azure, the function appears to work as coded. The error occurs when trying to send a Verify request to the Azure Function from Facebook Developer, specifically in Messenger's Webhook setup.

Comment: Why have all this commented out code if it is not relevant to the question? Likewise, the title refers to Messenger bot, but there is nothing left in the code relating to it. Can you simplify the question to its most minimal form to avoid any possible confusion? Also you need to mention the type of Function being used (e.g. Generic Webhook, ...)

Comment: Also, please detail how you are running the function (e.g. browser vs Function UI vs other tool), and exact what request you are passing (verb, query, body, ...)

Comment: Rob, if you could also provide the verification request being sent, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I would, but the request is coming directly from Facebook's server to the Azure Function. I'd have to setup a localhost situation to see what it is. I should point out that I'm looking at a JS solution because all of Facebook's examples are in JS. Before this test, I had a C# Function in place that was communicating correctly with Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when an empty (or non-json) body is sent to a Function with type WebHook. The handling is poor, and we are improving it per https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/849. This should be deployed within a week and you can then verify.

Comment: The first request from the Facebook API is always non-json. So I guess at least NodeJS Functions can't be used with Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Actually, I rephrased my answer after my initial post. It may be ok after the fix is in.